# I want to search string in associative array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [goal_status_name] => Not Started
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [goal_status_name] => Completed
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [goal_status_name] => Pending
        )
)
```

I want to search string value in above array if exist than count 1. If not exist than count 0 using php code.

```
$string = "Not Started";
$count = 0;
if(in_array($string, $data)){
  $count++;
  $val = $count; 
}
```

Comment: This is an array of objects, not an associative array

Comment: PHP 7+ - `in_array($string, array_column($data,"goal_status_name"))`

Comment: Ya sorry for typing mistake, I have used above code also but did'nt used for me

Comment: Not going inside if loop.
Using PHP 7.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Just to add the comment as an answer, as of PHP 7 you can use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with objects as input, so just use...

```
$string = "Not Started";
$count = 0;
if(in_array($string, array_column($data,"goal_status_name"))){
    $count++;
    $val = $count;
}
```

Comment: Are you using PHP 7 or above?  Do you get any messages (if you have errors displayed)?

Comment: Not going inside if loop.
PHP 7.2.1

Comment: @AmodKumar - Make sure that you have error_reporting and display errors turned on. A blank page can mean that you have some other PHP error that stops the execution of your code. All the suggestions/answers you've got should work. If they don't, then there are something else going wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this if it is array of objects:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    if($object->goal_status_name == 'Not Started'){
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not going inside if loop.
I am using PHP 7.2.1

Comment: It is possible, there is not so much information about object, this was just for simple objec

Comment: echo "<pre>";
print_r($data)
echo "</pre>";die;
above code showing array object as below

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [goal_status_name] => Not Started
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [goal_status_name] => Completed
        )
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [goal_status_name] => Pending
        )
)

Comment: @AmodKumar - Do you have `die;` before you run this code?

Comment: @AmodKumar - `die;` exits the script so nothing after will be executed.

Comment: ya exactly, thats y i m using die; to see the result of above loop whether showing or not;

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an associative array. You have an indexed array with objects.

You could to this with a simple foreach loop

```
$string = "Not Started";
$count  = 0;

foreach ($data as $obj) {
    if ($obj->goal_status_name === $string) {
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Now, after the loop, to see if at least one object contained that string, you can do:

```
if ($count > 0) {
    echo 'Match found';
}
```

If you want to know if *all* the objects contained that string, you can do:

```
if ($count > 0 && $count == count($data)) {
    echo 'All objects match';
}
```

`$count` will simply contain the number of matches.

Comment: Not going inside if loop.

Comment: @AmodKumar - Then you either don't have the data you're showing us or you've implemented it wrong. Please check the demo I added to the answer.

Comment: solution working for me but if all array of object having same string values as "Not Started" than only need to show match found, plz guide on same\

Comment: @AmodKumar - I'm not 100% what you mean, but I updated the answer.

Comment: @AmodKumar - If the answer solved your issues, please accept it so others know that the question has been resolved.